# how to check if tow docx file are same?

Tags: c#, docx

```
        public static string GetMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
        {
            using(var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                try
                {
                    using(var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
                    {
                        byte[] HashArray;
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
                        int i = 0;
                        sb.Append("0x");

                        HashArray = md5.ComputeHash(stream);

                        for(i = 0; i < HashArray.Length; i++)
                        {
                            sb = sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", HashArray[i]));
                        }
                        return sb.ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

i want to use GetMD5HashFromFile function above to get the file's hash value, and check if these are same.

and i create 1.docx file, and save as 2.docx, and i find this two files's hash are not same.  i don't know why , somebody can ask me why or give me a tip to solve my question.

Comment: Docx files are essentially Zip archives. In all likelihood, the Zip file entries in your second file have different dates/timestamps. Depending on the application you used to write the docx files, it could also be that the 2nd docx file contains different metadata (for example with regard to when the document was saved/modified the last time, author of the document, application used to write the docx, etc...) than the 1st docx.

Comment: FYI 1: You initialize the StringBuilder with an initial capacity of 256 characters. Note that MD5 is 128 bits long, or 16 byte. To represent 16 bytes in hex notation, you would only need 32 characters. So you could initialize your StringBuilder with an initial capacity of 32.

Comment: FYI 2: StringBuilder itself has AppendFormat(...) overloads taking format strings. So you don't need to use string.Format but can simply do `sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", HashArray[i]);`

Comment: I did as you said, but there was no difference.

Comment: in the Review tab there is a Compare button that you can try just in case

Answer (score 0):

thx elgonzo, but your prompt doesn't solve the problem. 
at least i know it's a zip file , and uncompress it, i get the document.xml, i found the different, the placement is different.
[different between two xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riA9s.png)

i write some code:

```
            string aLastName = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1,
            (fileName.Length - fileName.LastIndexOf(".") - 1)); 
        if (aLastName.ToLower() == "docx")
        {
            WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false);
            string strText = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.InnerText;

            return GetMD5HashFromStream(String2Stream(strText));
        }
```

But I don't think it's a good idea because XML can tell if it's the same.